# How to close the respective modal dialog when switch over to other modal dialog without overlapping - using Bootsrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Register-modal1,login-modal2 and forgot-modal3 page showing in model-dialog popup using bootstrap 3.Its working fine ,but when switch over to other model2 popup through anchor tag with in the popup model 1 ,which is overlapping model1(model2 overlapping on model1). Instead of overlapping it ,I just need to close it model1 when switch over to model2.

Please help me out, how to achive this by bootstrap 3

Comment: Just programmatically click on the close button.

Comment: That is functionality inside the modal 1 has through anchor tag switch over to modal2 , when do this how to avoid overlapping and how to make close possibility in this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a class to all three of your modal and trigger this :

```
  $('.myModal').modal('hide');
  $('.myModall').on('hidden', function () {
   $('#myModalNew').modal('show')
  })
```

or better make it a function so you can pass the new modal name to it !

```
function openNewModal(elClass,elID){
  $('.'+elClass).modal('hide');
  $('.'+elClass).on('hidden', function () {
  // Load up a new modal...
  $('#'+elID).modal('show')
 })
}
```

you can trigger it using on click or JQuery Click function.

Comment: Thank you Bardia, I have fixed my issue with your code suggestion without on(hidden,function). I have one doubt in that, why that on('hidden') function.could you please clear me .

Comment: You can either have it on('hide') which means as the other modal is going off the other one pops open on('hidden') makes sure that the other modal is completely is closed before opening the new modal.
it's just a way to make sure that all other modals with the same class are closed before opening new one, you don't necessarily need it it's just to my OCD with things :D

Comment: you can check bootstrap documentation on other events http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and link of bootstrap documentation